# ios uitableview - while scrolling, cells display wrong data before updating with correct data

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have a small problem with displaying data from server in UITableView cells.
I have an add that displays a "feed" screen, similar to the main screen on Instagram.
Each cell in the feed's UITableView loads and image and some text from the server (from parse.com)

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(HomeCell.reuseIdentifier(), forIndexPath: indexPath) as HomeCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let obj = tableArray[indexPath.section]
    cell.configureWithObject(obj)

    return cell
}
```

tableArray is an array of PFObjects

over at the HomeCell class, the configureWithObject methods loads the remote image for this cell using SDWebImage and sets the needed text labels

```
func configureWithObject(object : PFObject) {

    AppManager.sharedInstance().getTrackDetailsFromPost(object, block: { (error, obj) -> Void in
        if error != nil
        {
            return
        }

        var artworkURL = ""
        if let artworkString = obj?[Column.TracksArtwork.rawValue] as? String {
            artworkURL = artworkString
        }


        self.albumArtwork.sd_setImageWithPreviousCachedImageWithURL(NSURL(string: artworkURL))

        var trackTitle = ""

        if let title = obj?[Column.TracksTitle.rawValue] as? String {
            trackTitle = title
        }

        var trackArtist = ""
        if let artist = obj?[Column.TracksArtist.rawValue] as? String {
            trackArtist = artist
        }

        var trackAlbum = ""
        if let album = obj?[Column.TracksAlbum.rawValue] as? String {
            trackAlbum = album
        }

        self.songNameLabel.text = trackTitle
        self.songDetailsLabel.text = "\(trackArtist) - \(trackAlbum)"

    })
}
```

The problem:
When i scroll through the tableview, i see the wrong image and data on some cells for a split second, then the cell refreshes and displays the correct image and data.

How can i make the scrolling experience smooth and not have the cells keep reloading and refreshing data?

Thanks, Gil.

Comment: you're getting a reusable cell, already populated with data, so ensure you set all UI elements of the cell to default values in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  e.g. if you're asynchronously loading an image, set cell.image=nil before the async call.

Comment: @CSmith thanks, but wouldn't that just cause a "flickering" effect? when the image is set to nil and then to the required image?

Comment: @Gil What else would you show? If the image hasn't loaded, all you can do is show nil or a placeholder image.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight update the question with configureWithObject code

Comment: @CSmith is there a way to make sure the scrolling is smoth with no flickering or reloading data effect?

Comment: smooth scrolling and flickering are two different things.  When your images load asynchronously, set the UIImageView with a subtle fade-in animation (no flicker).  Scrolling that isn't smooth suggests some other performance issue.  @JamesFrost has good answer to your immediate problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, the fade in effect sounds like a good idea - i'll try that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `HomeCell` class, override the `prepareForReuse` method, and clear out your imageView:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    self.imageView.image = nil // or set a placeholder image
}
```

For example.

Comment: that 1 minor thing... <3